# htaccess: I need urgent help to remove %3f behind via form submit query generated urls

Tags: .htaccess

3 years with hosting at a2hosting. Today I noticed that every form query ends with %3f at the end of the generated url, which makes a 404. This happened suddenly.

This is my htaccess code that works for a years withotu any issue. It remove .php as extension, remove ?check= and replace it with /

```
# To externally redirect /site.com/foo.php?find=123 to site.com/dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\?check=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /site.com/foo.php?find=123 to site.com/dir/foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?check=$2 [L,QSA]


# Remove .php extension
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Code works to change for example query

```
from
https://www.whatever.org/whatever.php?check=msn.com

to
https://www.whatever.org/whatever/msn.com


Right Now i get 
https://www.whatever.org/whatever/msn.com%3f
```

I really need to remove %3f

Comment: Although the _cause_ does not seem to be your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: The cause of the problem, however, was my htaccess file. Strange, but that's how it is. The most important thing is that the problem has been solved

Answer (score 1):

Update.

After playing with htaccess code for some time it seems that this works. Changing

```
# To externally redirect /example.com/foo.php?find=123 to example.com/dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\?check=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

to

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php?find=123 to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\?check=([^&\s]+)(?:&(\S+))? [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2?%3 [R,L]
```

solved the issue and %3f behind query generated url is gone.

Comment: thank you. this worked for me. This appears to be a recent regression. I don't have access to the article but RH addresses it here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/7009378